# Typescript: How to map enum types with corresponding overlapping data

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a type that maps different enum types to expected data types, and want to make sure I'm able to figure out the correct type of the data by type inference.

```
enum Car {
    BMW,
    Toyota,
    Fiat
}

type CarWithData =
    | {
            type: Car.BMW;
            data: {
                doucheFactor: number;
            };
      }
    | {
            type: Car.Toyota;
            data: {
                dadFactor: number;
            };
      }
    | {
            type: Car.Fiat;
            data: {
                dadFactor: number;
            };
      };

function handleCar(car: CarWithData) {
    switch (car.type) {
        case Car.BMW:
            console.log(`BMW owner found with douche factor of: ${car.data.doucheFactor}`);
            console.log(`DadFactor: ${car.data.dadFactor}`); // TypeError as expected / intended;
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`Toyota / Fiat owner found with dad factor of: ${car.data.dadFactor}`);
    }
}

function getDadFactor(car: CarWithData): number {
    return car.data.dadFactor ?? -1; // Property "dadFactor" does not exist on type CarWithData
}

handleCar({ type: Car.BMW, data: { doucheFactor: 900 } });
getDadFactor({ type: Car.Fiat, data: { dadFactor: 10} });
```

This example illustrates what I want to accomplish. It works as intended with type inference in the switch statement in `handleCar`. However, the `getDadFactor` function throws a TypeError because "dadFactor" does not exist on the type CarWithData. What should I do here? I considered doing a union with a type that has all possible fields declared with type never, but that doesn't seem like good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to check the `car.type` first.

```
function getDadFactor(car: CarWithData): number {
  return car.type === Car.Toyota ? car.data.dadFactor : -1;
}
```

But, if this doesn't fit your case may be because you have too many cases you can add custom type guard to assert that car has `dadFactor` by doing the following:

```
const hasDadFactor = (
  arg: CarWithData,
): arg is CarWithData & { data: DadFactorData } => {
  return typeof (arg.data as DadFactorData).dadFactor === 'number';
};

function getDadFactor2(car: CarWithData): number {
  return hasDadFactor(car) ? car.data.dadFactor : -1;
}
```

The third option is to create a type with only cars that have `dadFactor`.

```
type CarsWithDadFactor<T extends CarWithData = CarWithData> = T extends T
  ? 'dadFactor' extends keyof T['data']
    ? T
    : never
  : never;
function getDadFactor3(car: CarsWithDadFactor): number {
  return car.data.dadFactor;
}
```

The trick in the third option is done with `T extends T` which you can interpret as a for loop in the union.

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nll7lN)

As of more generic version of the third option, we can another generic parameter that will indicate the type of the `data` that we are looking for:

```
type CarsWithSpecificData<D, T extends CarWithData = CarWithData> = T extends T
  ? T['data'] extends D
    ? T
    : never
  : never;


function getDadFactor3(car: CarsWithSpecificData<{dadFactor: number}>): number {
  return car.data.dadFactor;
}
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/NB8ppW)

Comment: Good suggestions. As you said, 1 would not work in my actual case cause this is a very simplified example.  I like option 2 & 3, however in my actual code there will be many different possible data types and creating type guards / types for all the different types will be a bit of extra work.

Comment: if we change suggestion 3 to accept another argument to check against the data object, will it work for you?

Comment: I think so, if I understand you correctly. Are you talking about adding another generic parameter to CarsWithDadFactor where the second generic is the keyof the CarWithData=

Comment: I meant passing the type for `car.data` as another generic parameter like here [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NB8ppW)

Comment: Yes, that was what I tried to formulate. This will do the trick. Thank you. Edit: Could you update the answer to include the newest addition from the playground?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is this:

```
type ExtractData<T> = T extends { data: infer U } ? U : never;

type AllDataTypes = ExtractData<CarWithData>;

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type CarWithPartialData = {
    type: Car;
    data: Partial<UnionToIntersection<AllDataTypes>>;
};

function handleCar(car: CarWithData) {
    switch (car.type) {
        case Car.BMW:
            console.log(`BMW owner found with douche factor of: ${car.data.doucheFactor}`);
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`Toyota / Fiat owner found with dad factor of: ${car.data.dadFactor}`);
    }
}

function getDadFactor(car: CarWithData): number {
    return (car as CarWithPartialData).data.dadFactor ?? -1;
}
```

Here we create a new type where the data type is the partial union of all possible data types. This is not pretty, hard to read, and requires casting but does have the correct functionality I'm looking for.